# interface getBean in test class

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an **interface**

```
@Component("a")
@Scope("prototype")
Public interface A{
.....
}
```

and the **b class** that implement interface a

```
public class B implement A{
  ...
}
```

and Junit test class

```
public class PartyTest {
    private static BeanFactory factory = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void loadSpring() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/spring/mainContext.xml"});
        factory = (BeanFactory) applicationContext;
    } 

    @Test
    public void personSaveTest() {
        A a = (A) factory.getBean("a");
    }
}
```

it throws

> org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No bean named 'a' is defined.

My question is, Why i cannot load interface? And if I use `@Component("b")` on the top of class `b` it can load class `B` but it can not load `interface A`.

Comment: post spring/mainContext.xml here

Comment: @Ruchira the component is created by annotations, not by configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring need a concrete "thing" in order to create a bean. So `@Component` is misplaced (should be on `B`). Same goes for `@Scope` which target a future bean (so something concrete).

Comment: If I place @Component on class B and remove it on the A interface, I can not load interface just i can load Bean

Answer (score 2):

Spring managed components are "real instances" of something, so they must always be instances of a concrete implementation (which must be concrete class). You cannot make instances of interfaces or abstract classes.

Note, that this has nothing to do with the type (what might have confused you): Of course, such instances are of any type in the type hierarchy up from the concrete class. In your example, an instance of B is of type B and A.

Comment: I want to load interface and use @qulifire for distinct between implementations. What should I do?